# What is the difference between having/not having a '/' at the end when defining a directory?

Tags: php, coding-style, directory, standards, opendir

When referring to directories in PHP such as in the code below.

`index.php`

```
if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/images/directory')) {

    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {

        ...

    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

The setup we can assume is below. The following denotes a `[directory]`, all code is in the `index.php` file and the imeages/files we wish to iterate through are in the `[images]` directory.

```
-[css]
-[js]
-[inc]
-[images]
-index.php
```

Specifically the `opendir('/path/to/images/directory')) {` line, **what are the best practices to referencing that directory?**

Should there be a trailing `/` at the end as it is a directory or is the unnecessary?
Should it be relative? Absoulte?
Could we use `SERVER_VARIABLES` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For realtive / absolute convention i suggest relative, but maybe is just me.
It allows your code to be relocated easier.

Then , curiosly , i checked php source code and opendir is wrapped around various c functions and one of those is

php_check_open_basedir

```
 313                 while (ptr && *ptr) {
 314                         end = strchr(ptr, DEFAULT_DIR_SEPARATOR);
 315                         if (end != NULL) {
 316                                 *end = '\0';
 317                                 end++;
 318                         }
 319 
 320                         if (php_check_specific_open_basedir(ptr, path TSRMLS_CC) == 0) {
 321                                 efree(pathbuf);
 322                                 return 0;
 323                         }
 324 
 325                         ptr = end;
 326                 }
```

So basically it loops in your path jumping from one DEFAULT_DIR_SEPARATOR to another.
So i guess, less you have the better is.

Also reading your code, but maybe is just my taste:
USing $dir."/".$filename  looks better than $dir.$filename

Anyway no real world difference i guess.

Comment: I mean in general, not just in relation to my code. My code was to give an example. What I suppose I am asking, is, **must** I always have a `/` at the end when defining a directory?

Comment: yes i meant generally.
the last / is not used really, difference is minimal, not noticiable.

For absolute or relative, i suggest relative, just in case someone should move his code around on other server / location.